# Small folder icon disappeared in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

My small folder icon disappeared (it is a white file icon instead of yellow folder icon). All other icons are present. If I use larger icons, all icons are present as well.

[image]

I already deleted and refreshed the icon cache. This does not solve the issue.
Restarting my PC, does not solve the issue either. Any solutions?

I use Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start the Registry Editor: `regedit.exe`
2. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`
3. If `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons` does not exist yet, create a new `key` named `Shell Icons` (so that `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons` now exists).
4. Inside, create a new `String Value` named `3`.
5. `Modify` this newly created `String Value` to `C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll,-4`.

   - `C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll` contains the standard icons.
   - 4 is the number of one of the icons.

This works for me on the PC having the issue. Two other PCs running Windows 8.1, however, do not have this issue and also do not have a `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons` registry key.

Note that `C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll,-3` does not ressolve the issue, since this uses the current default icon (which also explains the name of the `String Value`, `3`).